# Append a string to a list of unicode strings

Tags: python, string, list, unicode, concatenation

What I've tried:

```
>> abcd = [u'abcd']
>> abcd_ef = abcd + 'ef'
>> abcd_ef

[u'abcd', 'e', 'f']
```

What I'd like:

```
>> abcd = [u'abcd']
>> abcd_ef = **MAGIC ???**
>> abcd_ef

[u'abcd', 'ef']
```

Hopefully I made that clear enough!

Comment: Try providing the value as a list or use append to add to the list

Comment: You forgot to compile your Python interpreter with `--do-magic`, so you can't write `**MAGIC ???**` and have the code work. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a list:

```
>>> abcd = [u'abcd']
>>> abcd_ef = abcd + ['ef']
>>> abcd_ef
[u'abcd', 'ef']
```

otherwise the list adds each element (e.g. each character) of the string separately.

Alternatively, you can call `.append()` on `abcd` and modify that list in-place:

```
>>> abcd = [u'abcd']
>>> abcd.append('ef')
>>> abcd
[u'abcd', 'ef']
```

This is all standard python list manipulation and is independent of the contents; it doesn't matter if there are unicode objects or custom objects in that list.